# Regular Expression for null or Domain (Pattern) validation 

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

I want to validate text box by regular expression. It should be Null or valid Domain Name Like Google.com, example.com.

Thx

Comment: heres a link for the regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score 1):

Something along the following lines will work.

```
function isValidURL(url)
{
  return url.match(/([a-zA-Z]+:\/\/)?(.+\.)?(\w+)(\.\w+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/.+)?/) ? true : false;
}

alert(isValidURL(document.getElementById('textBoxId').value));
```

It won't work for things like "example.com" as really these aren't "valid" urls in that sense. A valid url beings with http://

Comment: Updated regex, try again